# Removing a message queue

Tags: c, ipc, message-queue

I am confused a lot with the ways message queues are removed in a C/C++ program.
I saw [here](http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/dynaweb_docs/0630/SGI_Developer/books/T_IRIX_Prog/sgi_html/ch06.html) that

> #### Removing a Message Queue
>
> You can remove a message queue using the ipcrm command (see the `ipcrm(1)` 
>       reference page), or by calling `msgctl()` and passing the `IPC_RMID` command 
>       code. In many cases, a message queue is meant for use within the scope of 
>       one program only, and you do not want the queue to persist after the 
>       termination of that program. Call `msgctl()` to remove the queue as part of 
>       termination.

And then something else which is [mq_unlink](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mq_unlink.3.html)

I am confused what is the way now to completely remove the message queue

Now Let me tell  the issue that I am facing.
I have in my application created 2 message queues
Now suddenly there is signal that comes and passes the control to a signal handler. In the signal handler, I am restarting the service in which I am facing an error saying `"Resource temporarily Unavailable"`. I have closed in the signal handler one of the queue's with `mq_close()`. May be the issue is coming since I am not closing the other one. But my doubt here is:

- Do I need to close it?
- DO I need to remove it?
- If I  have to remove it, Do I need to use `msg_ctl` or `mq_unlink`?

Comment: This "*In the signal handler I am restarting the service*" probably isn't a good idea.

Comment: Yeah I too agree and its a pretty old code which I am not supposed to change and I have to only do the trouble shoot the resource temporarily unavailable.

Comment: In case this issue is still open you might like to show us the relevant code snippets.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, there are two unrelated message queue implementations, the old UNIX System V one which uses `msgget()`, `msgsnd()` and `msgrcv()` and the newer POSIX compliant one [described here](http://linux.die.net/man/7/mq_overview).

If you are using the POSIX version, to close it just in your program you use `mq_close`, or to destroy it completely for all programs where it may be open use `mq_unlink`.

If you use the System V version to close the queue you must use:

```
msgctl(MessageQueueIQ,IPC_RMID,NULL);
```

where MessageQueueIQ is the ID of your queue.

to answer your other questions, if you are using the System V message queues, closing it is enough, if you are using the POSIX ones, you must unlink it (this will also close it).